# How do you refresh the dataset definition in report designer?

Tags: reporting-services

I keep getting:

> Dataset1 contains a definition for a field '[my Field name]' This field is missing from the returned dataset.

What I did was I removed the `[my Field name]` from the result set. I want dataset1 to be refreshed so it doesn't expect this field. How do you achieve that?

I already refreshed the fields in dataset1.

Comment: Have you tried rerunning the data query?

Answer (score 0):

Does the error text tell you where the error is? It might be a textbox or other control is using `[my Field name]`.

Comment: I think you are on to something.  I will watch out for this next time.  I ended up starting from scratch on the report which was giving me trouble.